# Today widget not respond after app update

Tags: ios, widget

I got a strange case for today widget.
My app has a widget to show some information to our user, widget has some button on it. User can click button to get different information.
    Here is the strange thing. I'm developing new version of my app. I need to test it. When I install a new ad hoc version app on the old version, My widget not respond. no update, no respond when i click on button. So I made some test case to solve it.

1. I install a new ad hoc version app on phone without old version app. Widget can respond.
2. I install a older test app than app store, then update it from app store, Widget can resond.
3. I install a older test app than app store, but update it from ad hoc archive with same version from app store, Widget can't respond.

If I delete widget and add it to today view , widget still can not respond.
All widget that can't respond can respond again if I reboot my iphone.

Anyone has face the same situation? Any help will be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: We have the same issue. Were you able to figure out more about this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Quite possibly a bug. The only thing I'd check for is if there are any crash reports for the widget. (Look in the "Devices" window of Xcode and choose your device and then choose "View Device Logs" I believe).

Comment: @decazuk Can you please share the solution to this issue? I am facing the same problem.