# iOS: Today App Extension shows no body or freezes after main app is updated

Tags: ios, widget, today-extension, app-update

I am unable to use the today widget after updating my app through AdHoc build installation. The today widget seems to freeze after the main app is updated.

I have referred to the following links but could not find a solution to it.

[Today Extension widget freezes when the main app is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937104/today-extension-widget-freezes-when-the-main-app-is-updated)

[Today widget not respond after app update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696347/today-widget-not-respond-after-app-update#)

I am facing similar issue as mentioned in the above two links. I have tried setting the preferredContentSize as below but doesn't seem to solve the issue:

```
CGSize currentSize = self.preferredContentSize;
currentSize.height = 85.0;
self.preferredContentSize = currentSize;
```

Issue gets resolved if we restart the phone.

Also please note that I am providing support for iOS 7 to iOS 9.3.5. Application is not iOS 10 compatible.

Please post your comments/suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change `preferredContentSize` in this method too:

```
- (void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize
```

it will look somewhat similar to:

```
- (void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize
{
    if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact)
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize;
    else
    {
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 100*myArray.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am sorry that I forgot to mention in my post, but this happens in the iOS 9.3.5 and I am not yet providing support for iOS 10 in my application.